Ellipsis with tože in Russian
Does anyone know literature on ellipsis with tože (тоже) in Russian? I've found papers only on verb-stranding, gapping, and yes/no ellipsis.
Here are some examples:
Я буду решать задачи. Я тоже буду (or Я тоже). (I will be solving tasks. I will be also)

Я готовил бургер. Я тоже. (I was cooking a burger. So was I)

In terms of constituents, I' or VP are targeted (*Я тоже буду задачи).
P.S. One could say: 'Я тоже готовил'. As a native speaker, I understand it to mean that I was cooking also, not necessarily a burger. The person I consulted admitted two readings (generic and specific (cooking a burger)).
Thanks in advance!
